# Error in git push?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I am following rails tutorial, currently rails version is 4.0.5.

after creating first_app project 
then

```
$bundle install
```

then generated secret token as mentioned there.
then

```
$rails generate rspec:install
```

then initialization and git add. After this when I typed

```
$git remote add origin git@github.com:mukeshthawani/firstapp.git
$git push -u origin master
```

then message came

> 'Warning: permanently added the RSA host key for IP address
>   '192.30.252.129' to the list of known hosts. permission denied . fatal: could not read from remote repository. please make sure
>   you have the correct access rights and the repository exists'

What should I do? I am not able to push.

Comment: Did you create a ssh key pair and uploaded your public key to Github?
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: @Bjoernsen I strongly suspect that this is indeed the problem, this looks like an answer, not a comment

Comment: SSH keys listed in your Github account should be matched with the one you have in computer. If not create a one and add it to Github.Then you will be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helps. Earlier it was automatically generated but after changing rails, keys were not uploaded, so I did that. :)